# Apache Beam Pipeline unable to insert data into BigQuery. Workflow failed

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to execute an Apache Beam Pipeline to insert data into BigQuery. I try to execute as follows:

1. Read the data from 2 files and join them together to create a `PCollection<Row>`.
2. From `PCollection<Row>` - create `PCollection<TableRow>` data to insert Data into BigQuery.
3. Write `PCollection<TableRow>` data into BigQuery

As I am writing data into BigQuery I am using following code:

```
tableRows.apply("WriteToBQ",
                BigQueryIO
                    .writeTableRows()
                    .to(String.format("%1$s:%2$s.%3$s", projectID, datasetName, table))
                    .withSchema(schema)
                    .withCustomGcsTempLocation(bucketProvider)
                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(deposition));
```

Where

- `tableRows` is type of `PCollection<TableRow>`
- `schema` is type of `TableSchema`
- `deposition` is like:

  ```
   WriteDisposition deposition = WriteDisposition.WRITE_EMPTY;
   if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("append", saveMode))
      deposition = WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND;
   else if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("overwrite", saveMode))
      deposition = WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE;
  ```

But I am getting errors when this block of code is executing. I am running this pipeline from Google VM. At the time of executing the pipeline, I am using a google service account and that service account's have all BigQuery related access permission as follows:

[image: Service Account Access Permission]

I am getting following errors [from google error log]:

```
{
    "insertId": "4084532125235872585:267295:0:233718",
    "jsonPayload": {
        "logger": "org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkItemStatusClient",
        "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_bq_job_LOAD_gcstobigqueryingestion_ea7dba97a19b40598216fbca9dbb1ac2_2fafaac857cbaf03a8b0b077946505ea_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob(BigQueryHelpers.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone(BigQueryHelpers.java:152)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle(WriteTables.java:318)\n",
        "worker": "gcstobigqueryingestion-07200511-yy9f-harness-vj8w",
        "message": "Failure processing work item dna-gcp-data;2021-07-20_05_11_45-2158642844235989413;3960257009366662958: Uncaught exception occurred during work unit execution. This will be retried.",
        "thread": "25",
        "job": "2021-07-20_05_11_45-2158642844235989413",
        "work": "3960257009366662958",
        "stage": "s32"
    },
    "resource": {
        "type": "dataflow_step",
        "labels": {
            "region": "XXXXX",
            "project_id": "XXXXX",
            "job_name": "gcstobigqueryingestion",
            "step_id": "",
            "job_id": "2021-07-20_05_11_45-2158642844235989413"
        }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-07-20T12:18:46.943Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "gcstobigqueryingestion-07200511-yy9f-harness-vj8w",
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "4084532125235872585",
        "dataflow.googleapis.com/log_type": "supportability",
        "dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id": "2021-07-20_05_11_45-2158642844235989413",
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_type": "instance",
        "dataflow.googleapis.com/region": "XXXXX",
        "dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name": "gcstobigqueryingestion"
    },
    "logName": "projects/XXXXX/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-07-20T12:18:56.899566777Z"
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.